# js get item[1] from nested array with item[0] = somevalue

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
GLOBALS = [
   [...],
   [...],
   [
       [...],
       ["searchValue", [<interestingInfo>]]
   ]
]
```

I want to find a way to get the  array based on the searchValue.

EDIT: here is my non working attempt:

```
GLOBALS.map(function(item){ 
    if(item && item.constructor === Array) 
        return item.map(function(itemLvl2) { 
            if(itemLvl2 && itemLvl2.constructor === Array) 
                return itemLvl2.map(function(itemLvl3) { 
                    return itemLvl3 && itemLvl3.constructor === Array && itemLvl3[0] == 'searchValue' 
                });
            else 
                return false;
        });
    else 
        return false;
})
```

EDIT: SAMPLE DATA / USE CASE

In need this in order to get all alias email addresses from gmail. You can get them when you open gmail and enter the following into the console:

```
GLOBALS[17][15][1].map(function(item) { return item[1]; })
```

Now I try to do this in a more generic way (i.e. not hard coding the array indices)

The search value is 'cfs'

Comment: I had some attempts with array.map, but struggle with the nesting

Comment: Why don't you use objects instead of infinite nested arrays? It will make your life much more easy.

Comment: Don't use `.map()` for searching, use it for mapping. Use `.find()` or `.findIndex()` for searching.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle I do not have influence on the GLOBALS variable. It comes from somewhere else and I have to deal with it :)

Comment: @Rajesh I have added the specific usecase (I hope you have gmail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, you can use recursion to get rid of hard coded levels.

**Optimisations:**

1. `if (JSON.stringify(array).indexOf(search) < 0) return;`. This will make sure if current object tree has specified value. If not, the entire tree will be skipped.
2. `Array.isArray(array)` will enfore check only on Arrays.
3. `array.indexOf(search) < 0` will check if search is in this array or not. If not found, value exists in some child node. This will also remove the dependency of just checking 1st value. Yes, this will add to performance, but will work even if order is changed.
4. `Array.some` because is will short-circuit loop on first correct value.

```js
function getSearchValue(array, search) {
  if (JSON.stringify(array).indexOf(search) < 0) return;
  if (Array.isArray(array)) {
    if (array.indexOf(search) < 0) {
      var r = null;
      array.some(function(item) {
        r = getSearchValue(item, search)
        return !!r
      })
      return r;
    } else {
      return array;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: perfect. I can now do getSearchValue(GLOBALS,'cfs')[1].map(function(item) { return item[1] })